# In pytest returns magicMock instance instead of return value

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

i have a sample method and a pytest method for it.

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime


# this is the method to test
def get_time_of_day():
    """return string Night/Morning/Afternoon/Evening depending on the hours range"""
    time = datetime.now()
    print(time.hour)
    if 0 <= time.hour <6:
        return "Night"
    if 6 <= time.hour < 12:
        return "Morning"
    if 12 <= time.hour <18:
        return "Afternoon"
    return "Evening"

#pytest method, where I am trying to mock datetime.now
def test_get_time_of_day(mocker):
    mock_now = mocker.patch("tests.test_sample.datetime")
    mock_now.now.return_value = datetime(2016, 5, 20, 14, 10, 0)

    assert get_time_of_day() == "Afternoon"
```

But when I try to run the pytest as follow

```
python3 -m pytest test_sample.py
```

I get **TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'MagicMock'**

I have a directory **tests** inside that I have the python file test_sample.py. In this file, I have written this code.

I have referred this [page](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/02/16/how-to-write-independent-unit-test-with-pytest-and-mock-techniques/):

So do anyone Know to solve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are assigning a value to `mock_now.now.return_value`, `datetime` **is already patched** and returns a `MagicMock` instead of the datetime object as you expect.

This would work:

```py
def test_get_time_of_day(mocker):
    dt = datetime(2016, 5, 20, 14, 10, 0)
    mock_now = mocker.patch("tests.test_sample.datetime")
    mock_now.now.return_value = dt

    assert get_time_of_day() == "Afternoon"
```

As you would typically patch objects in modules that you test (instead of within the test module itself), you would not run into this issue.

Comment: thank you, It worked for me. Also I got one more solution `def test_get_time_of_day(mocker):
    mock_now = mocker.patch("tests.test_sample.datetime", return_value=datetime(2016, 5, 20, 6, 10, 0))
    mock_now.now.return_value = datetime()

    assert get_time_of_day() == "Morning"`